# PyQt: How to use QMessageBox.open() and connect callback?

Tags: python, pyqt

How can I connect a callback when using `QMessageBox.open()` ? In the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QMessageBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QMessageBox.open) it says:

> QMessageBox.open(receiver, member)
> Opens the dialog and connects its finished() or buttonClicked() signal to the slot specified by receiver and member . If the slot in member has a pointer for its first parameter the connection is to buttonClicked() , otherwise the connection is to finished() .

What should I use for `receiver` and `member` in the below example:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QMessageBox
)

def show_dialog(app, window):
   mbox = QMessageBox(window)
   mbox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Information)
   mbox.setText("Message box pop up window")
   mbox.setWindowTitle("QMessageBox Example")
   mbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok | QMessageBox.StandardButton.Cancel)
   def button_clicked():
       print("message box button clicked")
       mbox.done(0)
       app.quit()
   # How to connect button_clicked() to the standard buttons of the message box?
   mbox.open(receiver, member) # What to use for receiver and member?

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.resize(330, 200)
    window.setWindowTitle("Testing")
    button = QPushButton(window)
    button.setText("Button1")
    button.setGeometry(100,100,100,30)
    def button_clicked():
        print("button clicked")
        show_dialog(app, window)
    button.clicked.connect(button_clicked)
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: are you looking for how to use the `open` function, or how to get a signal for a button click ? because if the latter is the case, you could try to connect to the `mbox.buttonClicked` signal instead ?

Comment: @Hoodlum I am experimenting with the `open()` method because I wanted to test it with `pytest-qt` and avoid blocking the program flow by calling `QMessageBox.exec()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found that I could simply use `mbox.open(button_clicked)` but I am still not sure how I can determine from within the callback which of the two buttons was clicked. Also one should not call `QMessageBox.done()` from within the callback since that would lead to infinite recursion. Here is how I call `QMessageBox.open()` which works, but I am still missing the last piece of the puzzle: How to determine which button was clicked?

```
def show_dialog(app, window):
   mbox = QMessageBox(window)
   mbox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Information)
   mbox.setText("Message box pop up window")
   mbox.setWindowTitle("QMessageBox Example")
   mbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok | QMessageBox.StandardButton.Cancel)
   
   #@pyqtSlot() # It is not necessary to use this decorator?
   def button_clicked():
       print("message box button clicked") # But which button?
       #mbox.done(0)  # Do not call this method as it will lead to infinite recursion
       app.quit()
   mbox.open(button_clicked)
   print("Dialog opened")
```

**Update**:

> How to determine which button was clicked?

You can use `mbox.clickedButton().text()`, for example like this:

```
def button_clicked():
    if mbox.clickedButton().text() == "&OK":
        print("OK clicked")
    else:
        print("Cancel clicked")    
    app.quit()
```

Comment: The link to the docs in the question is for PySide, but you're using PyQT. This seems to be one the occasions where the two are different. `mbox.open(button_clicked)` does not not work in PySide.

Comment: This seems to be the best workaround. If `button_clicked(self, btn:QAbstractButton)` were a meber of a QObject-derived class, you *should* be able to place the `@pyqtSlot(QAbstractButton)` decorator above it to tell the `open` function to connect it to the messagebox's `buttonClicked` signal. This does not seem to work though (results in a missing slot signature TypeError).

Comment: About the slot decorator: no, it's not necessary in this context as slots (like signals) can only be created at class level, so using it in an inner function will do nothing. Slot decorators are actually rarely required, and they are mostly intended for overloads with different signatures or special cases that do require exposure of custom slots, like when using the QMetaObject system (which is what happens when creating custom widget plugins for Designer). Note that you should also consider setting the `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute, otherwise the message box will continue to exist until quit.